# how to check number of jobs pending in queue in Azure Devops using restapi

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone know how to get number of pending jobs in agent pool using azure devops rest api?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same stuff, but there's nothing in Azure DevOps rest API documentation. It seems that for now MS does not provide such endpoint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).